# How to use using with CRTP?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef, crtp

When creating types with no additional features, I try to use `using`, rather than subclassing or using `typedef`.

I have a CRTP hierarchy where I am trying to propagate the concrete type up the tree.

`GrandKid` seems to compile fine.  Is there a way to get `GrandKid_2` to work?

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
junk.cpp:18:26: error: ‘GrandKid_2’ was not declared in this scope
```

**CODE**

```
template<typename T>
struct Parent
{
};

template<typename T>
struct Child
    : public Parent<T>
{
};

struct GrandKid : 
    public Child<GrandKid>
{
};

// using GrandKid_2 = Child<GrandKid_2>;   // doesn't compile

int
main( int argv, char* argc[] )
{
    GrandKid gk;  // ok
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @svick I updated the OP w/the error msg

Comment: `using` creates an alias, not a new type. Therefore, you cannot use `GrandKid_2` to define itself.

Comment: @arnoo ty - does that mean a `typedef` should work or is that also an alias?  I'm trying with `typedef` now, but running into problems - will keep trying.

Comment: The conceptual problem is, that you don't have a concrete type `GrandKid_2` to propagate to `Child`. You only have an alias for `Child<...>`, but a `Child<Child<Child<INFINITY>>>` obviously won't work. Or did you just want to make typedef for `GrandKid`? In this case a simple `typedef GrandKid GrandKid_2;` would have done (but I guess this wasn't your goal).

Comment: @kfmfe04 Yes, `typedef` creates aliases too.

Comment: @ChristianRau +1 ty for that clear explanation - you are right - that's not my goal - the problem is simplified (in RL, I have other template parameters that define GrandKid_2)

Comment: @arnoo +1 ty for the confirmation - I guess I must subclass then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using`, like `typedef`, creates an alias, not a new type. Therefore, you cannot use GrandKid_2 to define itself.

You will surely need to create a new type :

```
struct GrandKid_2 : Child<GrandKid_2> {};
```

<s>By the way, do you really want `GrandKid_2` to be its own child ? Maybe you meant `using GrandKid_2 = Child<GrandKid>`</s>

Comment: Seems it's time to ask what OP's going to accomplish by this

Comment: @AndyT aliasing is more convenient because I don't need to redefine my constructors to propagate back up the tree - that's why I prefer `using` and `typedef` when I can use them

Comment: I'm pretty positive `GrandKid_2` is really supposed to be `Child<GrandKid_2>`. That's what CRTP is generally about.

Comment: @Angew you are right - I will need to use the struct form and write out my constructors